# SelectedNode is not working after refresh always showing null

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

Here i am trying to show the last selected node after reload of treeview but the selected node is always null. I am able to find the tree node from the treeview node collection but not able to assign it to tree view. Please suggeest:

```
 public void LoadTreeViewData()
        {
            treeView.Nodes.Clear();// Clear any existing items
            treeView.BeginUpdate(); // prevent overhead and flicker
            LoadBaseNodes();//Populate all nodes

            treeView.EndUpdate();
            treeView.Refresh();
            treeView.ExpandAll();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(m_oSelectedNode_NAME))
            {
                TreeNode[] treeNodes = treeView.FlattenTree()
                .Cast<TreeNode>()
                .Where(r => Convert.ToDecimal(r.Tag) == Convert.ToDecimal(m_oSelectedNode_NAME))
                .ToArray();

                    treeView.SelectedNode = treeNodes[0];                   
                    treeView.Focus();


            }

        }
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: WinForms? ASP?  I can figure out what FlattenTree is doing, but it's not a standard function in the WinForm's TreeView control.  Wouldn't it just be `treeView.SelectedNode =  tns[0];`  Not sure why you are doing all that other stuff.

Comment: Here flatten tree is nothing but returning IEnumerable<TreeNode> collection to find me last save node.Its a winform control.

Comment: Here problem is although i found the tree node but when i assign to selectedNode . SelectedNode stays null.

Comment: Yes . It is decimal and its returning me the tree node but while assigning the selected node is null.

Comment: Your posted code works.

Comment: Its not working for me. After setting  treeView.SelectedNode .It is null always

Comment: Then you have something else going on that isn't posted.  We can't see that.

Comment: Thats all my code is

Comment: Do you have any TreeView events?  Post the code where you call `LoadTreeViewData()`.

Comment: Its happening when i am reloading the tree after save. First time its okay but when i refresh it will always null.

Comment: `Thats all my code is`  Clearly, you have more code to show.

Comment: I am calling this once i saved the folder name to data base and rebinding the tree and its failing

Comment: The only way "we" can help you is if you post code that we can use to duplicate the problem.  The current code you posted works.  Try it in a new project.

Comment: This refresh calling inside my after lable edit event .

Answer (score 0):

This problem is happening because i am trying to Update the selected node inside the Tree view after label edit event. I put a timer inside After label edit to resolve the issue and set the Selected node it works for me.

```
  var tnm = new Timer() { Enabled = true, Interval = 30 };
                                tnm.Tick += delegate {
                                    SetSelectioNode();
                                    tnm.Dispose();
                                };
```